# Is it possible to send multipart/form-data and receive application/json response ? (Laravel & Axios)

Tags: laravel, axios

Is it possible to send multipart/form-data and receive application/json response ?

In my frontend App I upload image using Axios:

```
    const { data } = await api.post('/image', formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      },
      onUploadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
        let uploadPercentage = parseInt(
          Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100)
        )
        console.log(uploadPercentage)
      }
    })

    console.log(data)
```

In Laravel endpoint I receive the image and store it, but I want to respond with JSON data

```
// Magic to store the image than send response
return response()->json(
    [
        'status' => true,
        'message' => 'Image upladed successfuly',
        'data' => $image
    ],
    200,
    ['Content-Type => application/json']
);
```

but no succes still receive the response Content-Type as text/html

is there a way to force the resonse to JSON ? or it is just not feasable because of the request type ?

Tried to set the response type to JSON but didn't work.